# Is there a wooden manikin whose position translates directly into software?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, 3d, drawing, modeling

I wonder if there is a wooden manikin of this type: 
[image]

That is connected to a computer such as its position is reflected into the 3D model.

I feel like this type of interface would be more effective than using a keyboard and mouse to pose a human like character.

Comment: A maybe cheaper alternative to Pepe Ochoa's answer would be mocap using multiple Kinect devices (quite cheap) and subscription software. That means you're becoming the manikin yourself.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but some people use midi controllers for animating poses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-ov6ATtx5U

Comment: There is always yourself. While mocap suits are still in the 2-3k price range, people have been using kinect cameras to control armatures. For posing for still drawing purposes search your mobile app store for "sketch pose"  to find several digital mannequins you can pose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems so! I know at least one, the [Qumarion](http://www.clip-studio.com/quma/en/products), offered by Celsys Inc., but from [reviews](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9-QUMARION/dp/B0095CZBDU) in Amazon, it's not very good (and quite expensive). The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfJ4pA8ngDo) looked good, though...

Answer (score 2):

For myself, I use DCC tools and properly set up (with joint constraints) IK and FK models, and have no problems with posing them.

I'd get frustrated pretty quickly with a manually-posed-and-reposed model as it'd be really darn hard to iterate poses for animation.